# selenium bug when trying to locate a link based on text

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Okay, so I'm trying to pull links from Craigslist. Specifically I'm trying to find links of class=result-title such as

```
<a href="/gbs/fee/6023288599.html" data-id="6023288599" class="result-title hdrlnk">NICE 2 BR NEAR BOSTON COLLEGE-  HT/HW INCLUDED - ON COMM AVE 9/1</a>
```

but for some reason the following code

```
        address = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('result-title')[i].text
        address2 = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text(address).text
        url3 =url2+address2
        print(url3)
        driver.get(url3)
```

Does not work.

For example, if it found the previous html link, `address2` would somehow end up being *NICE 2 BR NEAR BOSTON COLLEGE-  HT/HW INCLUDED - ON COMM AVE 9/1*, even though it should be */gbs/fee/6023288599.html*

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do here is :

Instead of getting the text of the web element, you can get an attribute value of `href` to get `/gbs/fee/6023288599.html` in the `address2`.

So,

```
address2 = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text(address).text
```

needs to be changed to

```
address2 = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text(address).get_attribute('href')
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: @ksmiles If this worked for you, please accept it as the answer.